# Issue in Creating windows virtual machine from customized Image created myself using azure CLI 2.0

Tags: windows, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to azure and I wanted to create new windows 2012 virtual machine from the image i just created using following steps.

1) Created  w2k12 virtual machine using following  azure cli 2.0 cmd

> az vm create -n W2k12-host -g Naresh-test --image
>   MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2012-R2-Datacenter:latest 
>   --vnet-name Naresh-test-vnet --subnet default --admin-username Administrator1 --admin-password R@ckware1234 --authentication-type
>   password  --storage-account  nareshteststorage --use-unmanaged-disk
>   --nsg Naresh-test-nsg

once the virtual machine is successfully created ,RDP to the vm & ran the sysprep script to make the vm as generalized .When  vm was in stopped state then i ran the following cmd to deallocate , make the vm state as generalized &  verified the state of the vm is vm-genralized

> az vm deallocate --resource-group Naresh-test --name W2k12-host
>
> az vm generalize  --resource-group Naresh-test --name W2k12-host

**I checked the image is in my resource group**

> [root@Az-test-cli ~]# az image list Location    Name
>   ProvisioningState    ResourceGroup
>   ----------  ---------------------------  -------------------  --------------- centralus   W2k12-Automation-host-image  Succeeded            NARESH-TEST

when I tried to run the  az vm create using following cmd

> az vm create -n Test-w2k12 -g Naresh-test --image
>   W2k12-Automation-host-image  --vnet-name Naresh-test-vnet --subnet
>   default --admin-username Administrator1 --admin-password R@ckware1234
>   --authentication-type password   --nsg Naresh-test-nsg --debug --verbose

**I get the following error**

```
At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "OSProvisioningTimedOut",
        "message": "OS Provisioning for VM 'Test-w2k12' did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for use as an image:\r\n * Instructions for Windows: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/ 
      }
    ]
  }
}  Correlation ID: 2fa53bea-4aab-46d3-b989-972607754bb7
```

I am not sure am I missing any other steps , please suggested me  if we have any other guide or document for the windows virtual machine image creation and vm creation using the customized image using azure cli 2.0

Answer (score 0):

> OS Provisioning for VM 'Test-w2k12' did not finish in the allotted
>   time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This suggests
>   the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image

If you are using the image that is not sysprepped (or **not correct generalize the VM**) to create VM, it could cause the error, so please make sure your image is sysprepped.

More information about Generalize a Windows virtual machine, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-generalize-vhd?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Note: Prior to capturing an image of an Azure virtual machine, it is recommended the target virtual machine be backed up, because Capture an image of an Azure widnows VM, this process **deletes** the original virtual machine after it is captured.