# Create large number of Linux machines failed with provisioning state `Canceled`

Tags: bash, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I'm trying to deploy large number of linux machines using the azure-cli (v 2.0.7) using this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

number_of_servers=12
for i in `seq 1 1 ${number_of_servers}`;
do
az vm create --resource-group Automationsystem --name VM${i} --image BaseImage --admin-username azureuser --size Standard_F4S --ssh-key-value ~/.ssh/mykey.pub &
done
```

The machines are created from a custom image.

When I ran it I got the following error :
`The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Canceled'.The operation has been preempted by a more recent operation`

I tried to create less machines but the error still exists.

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965752/issue-in-creating-windows-virtual-machine-from-customized-image-created-myself-u) but it does not solved my problem.

Comment: Does this work? `az vm create --resource-group Automationsystem --name VM1 --image BaseImage --admin-username azureuser --size Standard_F4S --ssh-key-value ~/.ssh/mykey.pub` If so, then remove in your script `&`.

Comment: @Cyrus it's working. If I will remove the & what will happen that I will need to wait until machine i will finish in order to create machine i+1. If I have 100 machines or even 10 machines it's a lot of time to wait

Comment: Have you considered using VM Scale Sets for that? `az vmss create` - it's built for these scenarios

Comment: @itaysk can I create the machines from custom image?

Comment: @liorko Do you mean create VMSS with custom image?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Yes, This is exactly what I need!

Comment: @liorko yes, we can, your image is linux or windows?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT linux machines.

Comment: @liorko we can use template to create VMSS with custom image, please check my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147022/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-liorko).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I create the machines from custom image?

Yes, we can use custom image to create Azure VMss.
We can use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-linux-customimage-autoscale) to deploy create vmss with custom image.

```
"sourceImageVhdUri": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The source of the blob containing the custom image, must be in the same region of the deployment."
      }
    },
```

We should store image to Azure storage account first.